# How to arrange data rows in by specific order of a particular grouping variable level in r

Tags: r, dplyr, grouping, arrange-act-assert

I want to know how to arrange data rows in by specific order of a particular grouping variable level in r.

Using the `mtcars` dataset, I want to create a data frame, called `mtcars_arrange` where rows are first organized by `gear` values in the following order:

```
> # desired gear order
> gear_order <- c(4, 3, 5)
> gear_order
[1] 4 3 5
```

Then, I want the dataset to be organized by a specific `carb` value:

```
> # desired carb order
> carb_order <- c(4, 1, 2, 3, 6, 8)
> carb_order
[1] 4 1 2 3 6 8
```

I know that you can use the `dplyr::arrange()` command to accomplish similar tasks, but I'm not sure what to do to get it to work for my purposes.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

---

---

Here is some scrap code associated with this question:

```
# dataset
mtcars

# unique values of gear variable
unique(mtcars$gear)

# unique values of carb variable
unique(mtcars$carb)

# desired gear order
gear_order <- c(4, 3, 5)

# desired carb order
carb_order <- c(4, 1, 2, 3, 6, 8)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We could convert to `factor` with `levels` specified as the vector objects created in `arrange`

```
library(dplyr)
mtcars1 <- mtcars %>% 
     arrange(factor(gear, levels = gear_order), 
            factor(carb, levels = carb_order))
```

Comment: Cool. Thanks. Is there any way to do this by specifying an order based on an external list, or something like that? That is, if the ```unique()``` command didn't produce the desired order and the user had a specific order in mind, can you use ```arrange()``` to accomplish the task using an external list?

Comment: @Mel You can just specify `levels = yourvec1` yourvec2 for each columns

Comment: @Mel I used `unique` only because the ones you showed is based on `unique` order

Comment: Sorry, I thought I pressed the check.